# useSelect second parameter

Tags: javascript, hooks, block-editor

I use the `useSelect` hook to retrieve data from the database when developing for the block editor.

Browsing the Gutenberg code, I see that in addition to the function parameter, `useSelect` has an optional second parameter that accepts an array.

Here is an example:

```
const { media, mediaUpload } = useSelect(
    ( select ) => ( {
        media:
            id === undefined
                ? undefined
                : select( coreStore ).getMedia( id ),
        mediaUpload: select( blockEditorStore ).getSettings().mediaUpload,
    } ),
    [ id ]
);
```

What's the use of `[ id ]` in this example?

In other case, an empty array is passed. Here is an example:

```
const { postId, isEditedPostNew, hasRemoteAutosave } = useSelect(
    ( select ) => ( {
        postId: select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostId(),
        isEditedPostNew: select( 'core/editor' ).isEditedPostNew(),
        getEditedPostAttribute: select( 'core/editor' )
            .getEditedPostAttribute,
        hasRemoteAutosave: !! select( 'core/editor' ).getEditorSettings()
            .autosave,
    } ),
    []
);
```

What's the use of `[]` in this example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short Answer

The second parameter for `useSelect` is the second parameter for [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), so check the React website and you'd understand what the heck that second parameter is.. :)

### Long Answer

`useSelect` is a custom React hook which uses the core `useCallback` hook in React which returns a [memoized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) callback which can avoid expensive calculations on every render, and if the second parameter for `useSelect` is provided, then as [documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#useSelect): ( `deps` is the second parameter, whereas `mapSelect` is the first parameter )

> *deps* `Array`: If provided, this memoizes the `mapSelect` so the same `mapSelect` is invoked on every state change unless the dependencies
> change.

And by "memoizes the `mapSelect`", it means that `useSelect` will call `useCallback` like so: `useCallback( mapSelect, deps )`, and thus the second parameter for `useSelect` is actually the second parameter for `useCallback`, and:

- If `deps` is an empty array (`[]`), `mapSelect` will be memoized and never be recreated.
- If `deps` is a non-empty array (e.g. `[ fooState ]`), `mapSelect` will also be memoized, but recreated **only if** the dependency (`fooState`) is changed.
- If `deps` is *not* an array, `mapSelect` will *not* be memoized, hence it will always be recreated.

So that means, as long as an array is provided, the `mapSelect` will be memoized (or you can say that it's being cached) so that on the next and all other renderings of the component, the same callback will be used instead of being created:

```js
// Although these callbacks use the same code, they're not exactly the same.
const callback = ( a, b ) => a + b;
const callback2 = ( a, b ) => a + b;
console.log( callback === callback2 ); // false

// Same as above; these are not exactly the same.
const callback3 = function ( msg ) { alert( msg ); };
const callback4 = function ( msg ) { alert( msg ); };
console.log( callback3 === callback4 ); // false

// So because of that, the following callback will be created on the initial
// render and then recreated on the next renders.
const onClick = () => console.log( 'clicked' );

// Therefore, if your callback is "heavy", then you can memoize your callback
// using the useCallback hook. And for example, the following callback will be
// created only on the initial render and then it's memoized so that on the
// next renders, the callback is not recreated and instead, the memoized one
// is used.
const onClick2 = useCallback( () => console.log( 'clicked' ), [] );
```

<sup>PS: The above `onClick` callbacks are just for demonstration purposes. In actual implementation, you wouldn't want to memoize such very basic code... because in that case, the optimization would cost more than not having it.</sup>

#### Note about the empty array (`[]`) vs non-empty one (e.g. `[id]`)

So React stated that:

> The array of dependencies is not passed as arguments to the callback.
> Conceptually, though, that’s what they represent: every value
> referenced inside the callback should also appear in the dependencies
> array.

Therefore, in the first example in the question, `id` is added as a dependency because it is referenced inside the callback, i.e. `select( coreStore ).getMedia( id )`, and if `id` isn't in the dependencies array, then the `id` value will always be the initial/current value by the time `useSelect` is called, i.e. before the callback is memoized.