# When to use the second parameter to useSelect?

Tags: block-editor

```
   const postType = useSelect(
            ( select ) => {
                console.log("RUN");
                return select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType();
            },
            []
        );
```

I have the above in a component. With [] I see 'RUN' 3 times. Without it I see 'RUN' 4 times.

I am trying to understand this. [This is helpful](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/388559/useselect-second-parameter) - but still not 100% clear.

In both cases the actual component is rendered 3 times.

My concern is that I won't want to miss updated data by using it. In this case postType doesn't change so I feel it is safe to use it and it seems to be a small performance optimisation.

But if the data changes? I am also wrapping this:

```
wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecords('taxonomy', "my_taxonomy", {per_page: 100})
```

in useSelect - because it will be null until loaded. But - and this is the part I do not understand, if I use [] I still get the updated data. (It is null the first time and the actual data the second). So [] does not mean - only run this once. It seems to mean - "do not recreate the function passed as the first param to useSelect" - but if it is still calling that function why would you ever want it to be re-created?

Sorry - probably this is not clear and I am just failing to even grasp the most basic point here - but if anyone can explain to me (probably in fairly simple terms) what is going on, that would be fantastic.

Or at least - when should I use an empty array and when not?

Thanks

Comment: [`useSelect`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/data#useselect) is a custom React hook that uses https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo and https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback, so reading these (new) React's API reference articles might help you further.

Comment: You can also read ablout useEffect dependencies if it is a little more in detail explained there:
https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But - and this is the part I do not understand, if I use [] I still
> get the updated data. (It is null the first time and the actual data
> the second). So [] does not mean - only run this once. It seems to
> mean - "do not recreate the function passed as the first param to
> useSelect" - but if it is still calling that function why would you
> ever want it to be re-created?

You would want the function to be recreated if the function was using a variable that changed. If you had something like this:

```
const posts = useSelect(
    (select) => {
        return select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'post', { author: authorId });
    },
    [],
);
```

Then the function is using `authorId` to get the posts from a specific author. Ideally if you change `authorId` then `posts` should change to the posts by that author, but because it was not passed as a dependency the function will not be recreated. The original function with the original author ID will continue to be used. So by passing the variable as a dependency the posts will always reflect the correct author:

```
const posts = useSelect(
    (select) => {
        return select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'post', { author: authorId });
    },
    [authorId],
);
```

If you omitted the `[]` entirely you would also get the correct posts any time the author changed. The problem is that the function would also run when the author *hadn't* changed, which is very inefficient.

Comment: thanks for this beautifully clear answer. @Jacob Peattie